# Remove leading and trailing white spaces in a csv file

Tags: python, regex, string, csv

Define:

`str = " a  , b,c, hello there !   ,   my name is +++ ,  g "`

How do I remove the leading and trailing white spaces so that I output:

`"a,b,c,hello there !,my name is +++,g"`

i.e. the output is such that there is no leading or trailing white space between values in a comma separated value string.

I started reading about Regular Expressions? Would this be an appropriate situation to use that? How would I go about completing the task?

Comment: replace with empty this: `/\s+[,\]]/g`

Comment: That's a SyntaxError. Is this a list of strings?

Comment: Is `str` a string or a list of strings? (ie `"[ a  , b,c,...]"` vs `['a  ',' b','c'...]`?

Comment: @LMc 'str' is a string. It is not a list of strings.

Comment: @roganjosh my apologies. It is just a string. Please see my amendment above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) and [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) like this:

```
','.join([item.strip() for item in my_string.split(',')])
```

**Output:**

```
>>> my_string = " a  , b,c, hello there !   ,   my name is +++ ,  g "
>>> ','.join([item.strip() for item in my_string.split(',')])
'a,b,c,hello there !,my name is +++,g'
```

**Explanation:**

[`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is used to split `my_string` by the separator `,` and the result is the following list:

```
>>> my_string.split(',')
[' a  ', ' b', 'c', ' hello there !   ', '   my name is +++ ', '  g ']
```

[`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is used to remove leading and trailing spaces from each item of the previous list:

```
>>> [item.strip() for item in my_string.split(',')]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'hello there !', 'my name is +++', 'g']
```

The above line is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

[`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is used to form the last result by joining the items of the above list.

Comment: thanks, this works! So basically you split at commas, and then strip white spaces from each element. But then I don't get the ','.join part?

Comment: Just edited to add more details, once we remove spaces around each word, we need to use `join()` to merge all those words to form one string.

Comment: Sexy non-regex answer +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strip` functionality

```
string = '     blah blah   '
print string.strip() # =>'blah blah'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use regex expression `'\s*,\s*'` to replace the matching content with `,`. For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_str = "[ a  , b,c, hello there !   ,   my name is +++ ,  g ]"

>>> re.sub('\s*,\s*', ',', my_str)
'[ a,b,c,hello there !,my name is +++,g ]'
```